# Place regex match from one column in to first column with NA by row

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a list of corrupted file-paths where in some cases the last directory got melded in with the name of the file (e.g. instead of `DIR/analysis/filename.csv` it's `DIR/analysisfilename.csv`). I have created a DF split on `/` and need to place extract `analysis` from the file-name and place it in the first preceding column that has a `NA` value.

Is there a way to do this in R?

Here is a small example with my current input and desired output

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- structure(list(a = c("MOX", "MOX", "MOX", "MOX", "MOX", 
                            "MOX", "MOX", "MOX", "MOX", "MOX"), 
                      b = c("FFTF", "FFTF", "FFTF", "FFTF", "JOYO", 
                            "JOYO", "JOYO", "JOYO", "JOYO", "JOYO"), 
                      c = c("FO-2", "FO-2", "FO-2", "FO-2", "MK-I", 
                            "MK-I", "MK-I", "B14", "B14", "B14"), 
                      d = c("L09", "L09", "L09", "L09", NA, NA, NA, 
                            "PTM001", "PTM001", "PTM001"), 
                      e = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                            NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                            NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                            NA_character_), 
                      f = c("analysisL09_1D_sampleJ", "analysisL09_1D_sampleH", 
                            "analysisL09_Multi-App_2DRZ", "analysisL09_2DRZ_new_bubble_gb_lim_DiffCoeff4_GrainGrowth", 
                            "analysisMK-I_50MW_new_bubble_gb_lim", "analysisMK-I_75MW_new_bubble_gb_lim", 
                            "analysisMK-I_50MW_old_bubble_gb_lim", "analysisB14_PTM001_1D_sample3_noAm", 
                            "analysisB14_PTM001_1D_sample1", "analysisB14_PTM001_1D_sample2")), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Current Output**

```
dat
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>    a     b     c     d      e     f                                             
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>                                         
#>  1 MOX   FFTF  FO-2  L09    <NA>  analysisL09_1D_sampleJ                        
#>  2 MOX   FFTF  FO-2  L09    <NA>  analysisL09_1D_sampleH                        
#>  3 MOX   FFTF  FO-2  L09    <NA>  analysisL09_Multi-App_2DRZ                    
#>  4 MOX   FFTF  FO-2  L09    <NA>  analysisL09_2DRZ_new_bubble_gb_lim_DiffCoeff4…
#>  5 MOX   JOYO  MK-I  <NA>   <NA>  analysisMK-I_50MW_new_bubble_gb_lim           
#>  6 MOX   JOYO  MK-I  <NA>   <NA>  analysisMK-I_75MW_new_bubble_gb_lim           
#>  7 MOX   JOYO  MK-I  <NA>   <NA>  analysisMK-I_50MW_old_bubble_gb_lim           
#>  8 MOX   JOYO  B14   PTM001 <NA>  analysisB14_PTM001_1D_sample3_noAm            
#>  9 MOX   JOYO  B14   PTM001 <NA>  analysisB14_PTM001_1D_sample1                 
#> 10 MOX   JOYO  B14   PTM001 <NA>  analysisB14_PTM001_1D_sample2
```

```
dat2 <- structure(list(a = c("MOX", "MOX", "MOX", "MOX", "MOX", 
                            "MOX", "MOX", "MOX", "MOX", "MOX"), 
                      b = c("FFTF", "FFTF", "FFTF", "FFTF", "JOYO", 
                            "JOYO", "JOYO", "JOYO", "JOYO", "JOYO"), 
                      c = c("FO-2", "FO-2", "FO-2", "FO-2", "MK-I", 
                            "MK-I", "MK-I", "B14", "B14", "B14"), 
                      d = c("L09", "L09", "L09", "L09", "analysis", "analysis", "analysis", 
                            "PTM001", "PTM001", "PTM001"), 
                      e = c("analysis", "analysis", "analysis", 
                            "analysis", NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                            NA_character_, "analysis", "analysis", 
                            "analysis"), 
                      f = c("L09_1D_sampleJ", "L09_1D_sampleH", 
                            "L09_Multi-App_2DRZ", "L09_2DRZ_new_bubble_gb_lim_DiffCoeff4_GrainGrowth", 
                            "MK-I_50MW_new_bubble_gb_lim", "MK-I_75MW_new_bubble_gb_lim", 
                            "MK-I_50MW_old_bubble_gb_lim", "B14_PTM001_1D_sample3_noAm", 
                            "B14_PTM001_1D_sample1", "B14_PTM001_1D_sample2")), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Desired Output**

```
dat2
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>    a     b     c     d        e        f                                        
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>                                    
#>  1 MOX   FFTF  FO-2  L09      analysis L09_1D_sampleJ                           
#>  2 MOX   FFTF  FO-2  L09      analysis L09_1D_sampleH                           
#>  3 MOX   FFTF  FO-2  L09      analysis L09_Multi-App_2DRZ                       
#>  4 MOX   FFTF  FO-2  L09      analysis L09_2DRZ_new_bubble_gb_lim_DiffCoeff4_Gr…
#>  5 MOX   JOYO  MK-I  analysis <NA>     MK-I_50MW_new_bubble_gb_lim              
#>  6 MOX   JOYO  MK-I  analysis <NA>     MK-I_75MW_new_bubble_gb_lim              
#>  7 MOX   JOYO  MK-I  analysis <NA>     MK-I_50MW_old_bubble_gb_lim              
#>  8 MOX   JOYO  B14   PTM001   analysis B14_PTM001_1D_sample3_noAm               
#>  9 MOX   JOYO  B14   PTM001   analysis B14_PTM001_1D_sample1                    
#> 10 MOX   JOYO  B14   PTM001   analysis B14_PTM001_1D_sample2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach. First, would filter to include data that definitively includes `analysis` in `f`, then remove it. Next would make the data longer. For each filepath, would put `analysis` in the first missing `NA` value. Finally make wide again.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  dplyr::filter(grepl("analysis", f)) %>%
  mutate(f = str_remove(f, "analysis")) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = "path", values_to = "value") %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(min(which(is.na(value))) == row_number(), "analysis", value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rn, names_from = path, values_from = value)
```

In base R you could do something similar like this as well:

```
dat$f <- sub("analysis", "", dat$f)
mat <- as.matrix(dat)
mat[cbind(seq(nrow(mat)), max.col(is.na(mat), "first"))] <- "analysis"
as.data.frame(mat)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 10 x 7
# Groups:   rn [10]
      rn a     b     c     d        e        f                                                
   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>                                            
 1     1 MOX   FFTF  FO-2  L09      analysis L09_1D_sampleJ                                   
 2     2 MOX   FFTF  FO-2  L09      analysis L09_1D_sampleH                                   
 3     3 MOX   FFTF  FO-2  L09      analysis L09_Multi-App_2DRZ                               
 4     4 MOX   FFTF  FO-2  L09      analysis L09_2DRZ_new_bubble_gb_lim_DiffCoeff4_GrainGrowth
 5     5 MOX   JOYO  MK-I  analysis NA       MK-I_50MW_new_bubble_gb_lim                      
 6     6 MOX   JOYO  MK-I  analysis NA       MK-I_75MW_new_bubble_gb_lim                      
 7     7 MOX   JOYO  MK-I  analysis NA       MK-I_50MW_old_bubble_gb_lim                      
 8     8 MOX   JOYO  B14   PTM001   analysis B14_PTM001_1D_sample3_noAm                       
 9     9 MOX   JOYO  B14   PTM001   analysis B14_PTM001_1D_sample1                            
10    10 MOX   JOYO  B14   PTM001   analysis B14_PTM001_1D_sample2
```